# Making an array of 20 books and their information

Tags: c++, arrays

So far i've tried :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int x;

    char books[20],isbn[20],type[20];

    int time[20],price[20];


    for(x=0;x<20;x++) {
    cout << "Enter the name of the book :" << endl;
    cin >> book[x];
    cout << "ISBN :" << endl;
    cin >> isbn[x];
    cout << "Type :" << endl;
    cin >> type[x];
    cout << "Printing time :" << endl;
    cin >> time[x];
    cout << "Price :" << endl;
    cin >> price[x];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I dont know how to output the informations entered by the user
and i dont know how to use OOP to define the book class

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You seem to know how to use loops and `std::cout` so where is the problem to use those to output the array entries?

Comment: i dont know how to use OOP to define the book class or how to sort them out

Comment: Then you need to refer to your learning material. Or get a better C++ book/course

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - you seem to have missed out the standard library namepsace (``std::cout``)

Comment: Did you read a book on C++? Looked into [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)? Are you allowed to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)-s?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the beginning. The question says. create an array of 20 books. Your code says

```
char books[20],isbn[20],type[20];
int time[20],price[20];
```

That's isn't an array of books, it's five separate arrays (and some of them are wrong). What you should do is this

```
struct Book
{
    char title[100];
    char isbn[15];
    int type;
    int time;
    int price;
};

int main()
{
    Book books[20];
    ...
}
```

Now at least you have an array of 20 books. You can carry on from here.

Programming is **much** easier if you get the first steps right, writing more code on top of bad code is hard.

Comment: Why not `std::string title;` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Taking a guess, the OP is on a course that forbids the use of `std::string`, at least until it's been covered in lessons.

Comment: Ahh yes, you're probably correct:  the "let's teach C++ badly" approach.  As if it was C.  This makes [Kate Gregory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) cry.